# Number of combinations (N choose R) in C++

Tags: c++, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Here I try to write a program in C++ to find NCR. But I've got a problem in the result. It is not correct. Can you help me find what the mistake is in the program?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fact(int n){
    if(n==0) return 1;
    if (n>0) return n*fact(n-1);
};

int NCR(int n,int r){
    if(n==r) return 1;
    if (r==0&&n!=0) return 1;
    else return (n*fact(n-1))/fact(n-1)*fact(n-r);
};

int main(){
    int n;  //cout<<"Enter A Digit for n";
    cin>>n;
    int r;
         //cout<<"Enter A Digit for r";
    cin>>r;
    int result=NCR(n,r);
    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your formula is wrong, it has `fact(n-1)` in both numerator and denominator (they cancel).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 40):

Your formula is totally wrong, it's supposed to be `fact(n)/fact(r)/fact(n-r)`, but that is in turn a very inefficient way to compute it.

See [Fast computation of multi-category number of combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107653/fast-computation-of-multi-category-number-of-combinations) and especially my comments on that question.  (Oh, and please reopen that question also so I can answer it properly)

The single-split case is actually very easy to handle:

```
unsigned nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k )
{
    if (k > n) return 0;
    if (k * 2 > n) k = n-k;
    if (k == 0) return 1;

    int result = n;
    for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
        result *= (n-i+1);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/aDJXNO

If the result doesn't fit, you can calculate the sum of logarithms and get the number of combinations inexactly as a double.  Or use an arbitrary-precision integer library.

---

I'm putting my solution to the other, closely related question here, because ideone.com has been losing code snippets lately, and the other question is still closed to new answers.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > factor_table;
void fill_sieve( int n )
{
    factor_table.resize(n+1);
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
        factor_table[i] = std::pair<int, int>(i, 1);
    for( int j = 2, j2 = 4; j2 <= n; (j2 += j), (j2 += ++j) ) {
        if (factor_table[j].second == 1) {
            int i = j;
            int ij = j2;
            while (ij <= n) {
                factor_table[ij] = std::pair<int, int>(j, i);
                ++i;
                ij += j;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<unsigned> powers;

template<int dir>
void factor( int num )
{
    while (num != 1) {
        powers[factor_table[num].first] += dir;
        num = factor_table[num].second;
    }
}

template<unsigned N>
void calc_combinations(unsigned (&bin_sizes)[N])
{
    using std::swap;

    powers.resize(0);
    if (N < 2) return;

    unsigned& largest = bin_sizes[0];
    size_t sum = largest;
    for( int bin = 1; bin < N; ++bin ) {
        unsigned& this_bin = bin_sizes[bin];
        sum += this_bin;
        if (this_bin > largest) swap(this_bin, largest);
    }
    fill_sieve(sum);

    powers.resize(sum+1);
    for( unsigned i = largest + 1; i <= sum; ++i ) factor<+1>(i);
    for( unsigned bin = 1; bin < N; ++bin )
        for( unsigned j = 2; j <= bin_sizes[bin]; ++j ) factor<-1>(j);
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned bin_sizes[] = { 8, 1, 18, 19, 10, 10, 7, 18, 7, 2, 16, 8, 5, 8, 2, 3, 19, 19, 12, 1, 5, 7, 16, 0, 1, 3, 13, 15, 13, 9, 11, 6, 15, 4, 14, 4, 7, 13, 16, 2, 19, 16, 10, 9, 9, 6, 10, 10, 16, 16 };
    calc_combinations(bin_sizes);
    char* sep = "";
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < powers.size(); ++i ) {
        if (powers[i]) {
            std::cout << sep << i;
            sep = " * ";
            if (powers[i] > 1)
                std::cout << "**" << powers[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: A heads up to readers the nChoosek code is missing the case where n = k
This is always equal to one, just remember to add that condition.

Comment: @IAmRoot Looks like the n = k case will be handled by     if (k * 2 > n) k = n-k; (k is now 0) and  if (k == 0) return 1;

Comment: @dodecaplex: Exactly so.  It also would not have hurt anything to enter the loop, there's just no reason to, and as you point out, the early exit optimization does cover that case.

Comment: @IAmRoot never overcomplicate things.

Comment: Warning: `nChoosek()` is wrong! `result /= i;` must be divisible, if we add line `assert(0 == (result % i));` just before this line, and calc e.g. nChoosek(64, 7), you will see this assertion fails with: 53546048 7 (i.e 53546048 / 7 = 7649435.428571428), not a whole number.

Comment: E.g. nChoosek(64, 7) returns 7649435, while https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php c(64, 7) =  621216192.

Comment: The following `NCR()` from Steven is correct, which gives correct answer: NCR(64, 7) = 621216192. And the assertion `assert(0 == (res % k));` always hold if you add it before `res /= k;`.

Comment: @user873275: There's nothing wrong with that line, as any group of `i` consecutive numbers is guaranteed to include `i` as a factor of at least one of them.  There is however something wrong with your test case (you've already overflowed)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: can you run your program with a *REAL* compiler to calc nChoosek(64, 7)! you will see the problem for yourself!

Comment: @user873275: The inputs 64 and 7 don't work with 32-bit arithmetic.  They work fine with 64-bit arithmetic.  Select the data type appropriate for the inputs.  It's not a problem with the algorithm or its implementation.

Comment: Yes, it's a overflow problem, the `result` type need to be declared the longest int possible: unsigned long long.

Comment: @user873275: That's a waste unless your inputs require it.  Or insufficient if your inputs are even larger; then you should use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library.  But if the inputs don't calculate correct in `int` or `unsigned`, then both the type of variable `result` and the return type of the function should be widened.

Answer (score 18):

The definition of N choose R is to compute the two products and divide one with the other,

(N * N-1 * N-2 * ... * N-R+1) / (1 * 2 * 3 * ... * R)

However, the multiplications may become too large really quick and overflow existing data type. The implementation trick is to reorder the multiplication and divisions as,

(N)/1 * (N-1)/2 * (N-2)/3 * ... * (N-R+1)/R

It's guaranteed that at each step the results is divisible (for n continuous numbers, one of them must be divisible by n, so is the product of these numbers).

For example, for N choose 3, at least one of the N, N-1, N-2 will be a multiple of 3, and for N choose 4, at least one of N, N-1, N-2, N-3 will be a multiple of 4.

C++ code given below.

```
int NCR(int n, int r)
{
    if (r == 0) return 1;

    /*
     Extra computation saving for large R,
     using property:
     N choose R = N choose (N-R)
    */
    if (r > n / 2) return NCR(n, n - r); 

    long res = 1; 

    for (int k = 1; k <= r; ++k)
    {
        res *= n - k + 1;
        res /= k;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: should `res` be `long` at all?

Comment: Just for situations that the res *= n - k + 1 step overflow before the division happens.

Comment: NOTE: this should be the correct answer instead of the top voted Ben's answer of `nChoosek()`. `NCR(64, 7) = 621216192`. And the assertion `assert(0 == (res % k));` always hold if you add it before `res /= k;`.

Comment: @user873275: It does exactly the same operations as mine.

Comment: @user873275: What does Steven have after running the first loop iteration (`k == 1`)?  Oh yeah, it multiplies by `n` and divides by `1`, reaching my same starting point.  Of course that property holds, Steven spends the first 2/3rds of his answer explaining why.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Steven's solution using `res` type `long`, your solution using `result` type `int`, it overflows.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to implement n-choose-k is to base it not on factorial, but on a "rising product" function which is closely related to the factorial.

The rising_product(m, n) multiplies together m * (m + 1) * (m + 2) * ... * n, with rules for handling various corner cases, like n >= m, or n <= 1:

See [here](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/arith.c) for an implementation nCk as well as nPk  as a intrinsic functions in an interpreted programming language written in C:

```
static val rising_product(val m, val n)
{
  val acc;

  if (lt(n, one))
    return one;

  if (ge(m, n))
    return one;

  if (lt(m, one))
    m = one;

  acc = m;

  m = plus(m, one);

  while (le(m, n)) {
    acc = mul(acc, m);
    m = plus(m, one);
  }

  return acc;
}

val n_choose_k(val n, val k)
{
  val top = rising_product(plus(minus(n, k), one), n);
  val bottom = rising_product(one, k);
  return trunc(top, bottom);
}

val n_perm_k(val n, val k)
{
  return rising_product(plus(minus(n, k), one), n);
}
```

This code doesn't use operators like `+` and `<` because it is type generic (the type `val` represents a value of any kinds, such as various kinds of numbers including "bignum" integers) and because it is written in C (no overloading), and because it is the basis for a Lisp-like language that doesn't have infix syntax.

In spite of that, this n-choose-k implementation has a simple structure that is easy to follow.

Legend: `le`: less than or equal; `ge`: greater than or equal; `trunc`: truncating division; `plus`: addition, `mul`: multiplication, `one`: a `val` typed constant for the number one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `double` instead of `int`.

**UPDATE:**

Your formula is also wrong. You should use `fact(n)/fact(r)/fact(n-r)`

Comment: Yes! I didn't care to check the formula because using `int` would also produce wrong results there.

Comment: Even using `double` is not a very good approach.  Try to compute `6000 choose 3`.  It fits easily in a 32-bit `int`, but using that formula and doubles will fail miserably.

Comment: oops... I meant `600 choose 3` easily fits.   `6000 choose 3` actually doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

the line

```
else return (n*fact(n-1))/fact(n-1)*fact(n-r);
```

should be

```
else return (n*fact(n-1))/(fact(r)*fact(n-r));
```

or even

```
else return fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r));
```

Comment: You're making some of the same mistakes as the OP... `fact(n-r)` needs to be a divisor, not a multiplicative factor.

Answer (score 1):

this is for reference to not to get time limit exceeded while solving nCr in competitive programming,i am posting this as it will be helpful to u as you already got answer for ur question,
Getting the prime factorization of the binomial coefficient is probably the most efficient way to calculate it, especially if multiplication is expensive.  This is certainly true of the related problem of calculating factorial (see [Click here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm) for example).

Here is a simple algorithm based on the Sieve of Eratosthenes that calculates the prime factorization.  The idea is basically to go through the primes as you find them using the sieve, but then also to calculate how many of their multiples fall in the ranges [1, k] and [n-k+1,n].  The Sieve is essentially an O(n \log \log n) algorithm, but there is no multiplication done.  The actual number of multiplications necessary once the prime factorization is found is at worst O\left(\frac{n \log \log n}{\log n}\right) and there are probably faster ways than that.

```
prime_factors = []

n = 20
k = 10

composite = [True] * 2 + [False] * n

for p in xrange(n + 1):
if composite[p]:
    continue

q = p
m = 1
total_prime_power = 0
prime_power = [0] * (n + 1)

while True:

    prime_power[q] = prime_power[m] + 1
    r = q

    if q <= k:
        total_prime_power -= prime_power[q]

    if q > n - k:
        total_prime_power += prime_power[q]

    m += 1
    q += p

    if q > n:
        break

    composite[q] = True

prime_factors.append([p, total_prime_power])

 print prime_factors
```

Comment: Please note the code I provided 3 years earlier in my answer not only does this without use of dynamic list growth, it also uses the factorizations to solve the number-of-combinations problem.  And in the language the question asked for (I guess the one here is python?).

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function is used incorrectly here. `fact()` function should be changed into this:

```
int fact(int n){
if(n==0||n==1) //factorial of both 0 and 1 is 1. Base case.
{
    return 1;
}else

    return (n*fact(n-1));//recursive call.
```

};

Recursive call should be made in `else` part.

`NCR()` function should be changed into this:

```
int NCR(int n,int r){
    if(n==r) {
        return 1;
    } else if (r==0&&n!=0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(r==1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// CPP program To calculate The Value Of nCr
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int fact(int n);

int nCr(int n, int r)
{
    return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r));
}

// Returns factorial of n
int fact(int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res = res * i;
    return res;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int n = 5, r = 3;
    cout << nCr(n, r);
    return 0;
}
```