# nCk modulo p when n % p or k % p == 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to solve a coding challenge on hacker rank which requires one to calculate binomial coefficients mod a prime, i.e.

```
nchoosek(n, k, p)
```

I'm using the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n) that works for the first three sets of inputs but begins failing on the 4th. I stepped through it in the debugger and determined that the issue arises when:

```
n % p == 0 || k % p == 0
```

I just need to know how to modify my current solution to handle the specific cases where n % p == 0 or k % p == 0. None of the answers I've found on stack exchange seem to address this specific case. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

long long FactorialExponent(long long n, long long p)
{
    long long ex = 0;
    do
    {
        n /= p;
        ex += n;
    }while(n > 0);
    return ex;
}

unsigned long long ModularMultiply(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long p) {
  unsigned long long a1 = (a >> 21), a2 = a & ((1ull << 21) - 1);
  unsigned long long temp = (a1 * b) % p;   // doesn't overflow under the assumptions
  temp = (temp << 21) % p;                  // this neither
  temp += (a2 * b) % p;                       // nor this
  return temp % p;
}

unsigned long long ModularInverse(unsigned long long k, unsigned long m) {
    if (m == 0) return (k == 1 || k == -1) ? k : 0;
    if (m < 0) m = -m;
    k %= m;
    if (k < 0) k += m;
    int neg = 1;
    unsigned long long p1 = 1, p2 = 0, k1 = k, m1 = m, q, r, temp;
    while(k1 > 0) {
      q = m1 / k1;
      r = m1 % k1;
      temp = q*p1 + p2;
      p2 = p1;
      p1 = temp;
      m1 = k1;
      k1 = r;
      neg = !neg;
    }
    return neg ? m - p2 : p2;
}

// Preconditions: 0 <= k <= min(n,p-1); p > 1 prime
unsigned long long ChooseModTwo(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k, unsigned long p)
{
    // reduce n modulo p
    n %= p;

    // Trivial checks
    if (n < k) {

        return 0;
    }

    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Now 0 < k < n, save a bit of work if k > n/2
    if (k > n/2) {
        k = n-k;
    }
    // calculate numerator and denominator modulo p
    unsigned long long num = n, den = 1;
    for(n = n-1; k > 1; --n, --k)
    {
        num = ModularMultiply(num, n, p);
        den = ModularMultiply(den, k, p);
    }

    den = ModularInverse(den,p);
    return ModularMultiply(num, den, p);
}

// Preconditions: 0 <= k <= n; p > 1 prime
long long ChooseModOne(long long n, long long k, const unsigned long p)
{
    // For small k, no recursion is necessary
    if (k < p) return ChooseModTwo(n,k,p);
    unsigned long long q_n, r_n, q_k, r_k, choose;
    q_n = n / p;
    r_n = n % p;
    q_k = k / p;
    r_k = k % p;

    choose = ChooseModTwo(r_n, r_k, p);
    // If the exponent of p in choose(n,k) isn't determined to be 0
    // before the calculation gets serious, short-cut here:
    // if (choose == 0) return 0;
    return ModularMultiply(choose, ChooseModOne(q_n, q_k, p), p);

}

unsigned long long ModularBinomialCoefficient(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k, const unsigned long p)
{
    // We deal with the trivial cases first
    if (k < 0 || n < k) return 0;
    if (k == 0 || k == n) return 1;
    // Now check whether choose(n,k) is divisible by p
    if (FactorialExponent(n, p) > FactorialExponent(k, p) + FactorialExponent(n - k, p)) return 0;
    // If it's not divisible, do the generic work
    return ChooseModOne(n, k, p);
}

int main() {

  //std::ifstream fin ("input03.txt");
  std::ifstream fin ("test.in");

  int kMod = 1000003;
  int T;
  fin >> T;
  int N = T;
  //std::cin >> T;

  unsigned long long n, k;
  unsigned long long a, b;
  int result[N];
  int index = 0;

  while (T--) {

    fin >> n >> k;

    a = ModularBinomialCoefficient(n - 3, k, kMod);
    b = ModularBinomialCoefficient(n + k, n - 1, kMod);

    // (1 / (n + k) * nCk(n - 3, k) * nCk(n + k, n - 1)) % 1000003
    unsigned long long x = ModularMultiply(a, b, kMod);
    unsigned long long y = ModularMultiply(x, ModularInverse((n + k), kMod), kMod);

    result[index] = y;
    index++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    std::cout << result[i] << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

Input:
6
90 13
65434244 16341234
23424244 12341234
424175 341198
7452123  23472
56000168 16000048

Output:
815483
715724
92308
903465
241972
0 <-- Incorrect, should be: 803478
```

Constraints:
4 <= N <= 10^9
1 <= K <= N

Comment: How big is `n`?  Can it be too big for a machine integer, or only nCr is?

Comment: n can be as large as 10^9, but that isn't the issue I'm having. I've tested the program with n and k larger than the inputs that are failing and gotten the proper answer. The problem, which I specified in OP is specifically when n % p == 0 or k % p == 0.

Comment: According to the test input n = 56000168, k = 16000048 should return an answer of 803478. Both n and k modulo p are 0 in this case and there's a specific point in ChooseModTwo() where this causes the output of the program to be 0.

Comment: What is the range of `p`?

Comment: p is a constant, 1000003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) to reduce the problem to ceil(log_P(N)) subproblems with `k, n < p`: Write `n = n_m * p^m + ... + n_0` and `k = k_m * p^m + ... + k_0` in base `p` (`n_i, k_i < p` are the digits), then we have

```
C(n,k) = PROD(i = 0 to m, C(n_i, k_i))  (mod p)
```

The subproblems are easy to solve, because every factor of `k!` has an inverse modulo p. You get an algorithm with runtime complexity O(p log(n)), which is better than that of Ivaylo's code in case of `p << n`, if I understand it correctly.

```
int powmod(int x, int e, int p) {
    if (e == 0) return 1;
    if (e & 1) return (long long)x * powmod(x, e - 1, p) % p;
    long long rt = powmod(x, e / 2, p);
    return rt * rt % p;
}

int binom_coeff_mod_prime(int n, int k, int p) {
    long long res = 1;
    while (n || k) {
        int N = n % p, K = k % p;
        for (int i = N - K + 1; i <= N; ++i)
            res = res * i % p;
        for (int i = 1; i <= K; ++i)
            res = res * powmod(i, p - 2, p) % p;
        n /= p;
        k /= p;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I don't understand how to adapt the theorem to my code. Do you have a link to some working code? I've searched for it myself but haven't found a link to any code, just the theorem. I'm not smart enough to figure out how read the theorem and adapt it myself. I also have a suspicion that the code I'm using is taking all that into consideration already.

Comment: @JeremiahBiard Write n = n_k n_{k-1} ... n_1 and m = m_k m_{k-1} ... m_1 in base p (n_i and m_i are the digits to base p). Then C(n,m) % p = PROD(i = 1 to k, C(n_i, m_i)) % p. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey! So that gets me past the initial issue I was having, now I'm running into the same issue in the ModularInverse() function where it calculates k % m.

Comment: @JeremiahBiard I don't know what you mean by "when it calculates k % m" (what's m and why do you want to calculate k % m?). I added the implementation of `powmod`, that makes my code self-contained. It should illustrate the concept as well, in case you want to use your existing code

Comment: It's in the ModularInverse() function and not related to your code at all. As you can see from my code to get the final answer I need to calculate 1 / (n + k) * nCk(n - 3, k) * nCk(n + k, n - 1). Since there's no modular division I need to calculate the modular inverse of (n + k) and multiply it by the other two results. In this case, k = (n + k) and m is the prime 1000003. Specificall this line: unsigned long long y = ModularMultiply(x, ModularInverse((n + k), kMod), kMod);

Comment: @JeremiahBiard Well that's a different problem. `n + k` does not necessarily *have* an inverse modulo p.

Comment: @JeremiahBiard What's the task where this occurs? It's very likely that there exists a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use factorization to compute the number of combinations without division.  I've got code for doing so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331125/103167), originally inspired by [Fast computation of multi-category number of combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9107653/103167) (I still would like to post a proper answer to that, if some kind souls would reopen it).

My code stores the result as a table of factors, doing the modular multiplication to expand the result should be quite straightforward.

Probably not practical for n in the range of 10**9, though, since the sieve will be quite massive and take a while to construct.

Comment: Yeah, not practical at all, I added the constraints after the code, the solution needs to handle: 4 <= N <= 10^9;  1 <= K <= N

Comment: @JeremiahBiard: Still, you might try eliminating the modular division by finding a numerator term that each denominator term divides exactly.